# What would be the negation of the following statement

Tags: logic, argumentation

"I sometimes work on Monday night"

- I'm struggling with the word 'sometimes'. Any advice on how to deal with this word?

Comment: Sometime must be transalted with the **existential** quantifier.

Comment: There is an **x** such that **(Moday_night(x) and I_work_on(x))**.

Comment: in English.. perhaps 'infrequently'?

Comment: You can express your idea if we had more specifics. I can Express this several ways: Every month I rotate working Monday nights: I work overtime usually on Monday nights; etc. The message as written expresses you work some Mondays and some Mondays you are off. The negation of SOME is SOME  . . ARE NOT . . .   This would express I do not work on every Monday or I never work on Monday.

Comment: You might like to visit [ell.se] for questions like this.

Answer (score 3):

How often do you work on Monday nights? a) Never. b) Very rarely. c) Sometimes. d) Quite often. e) Almost always. f) Always.

So the negation would be: I either work on Monday nights very rarely or never, or at least quite often.

Mathematicians may use "sometimes" meaning "at least once", so to them the negation of "sometimes" would be "never". But most people are not mathematicians.

Comment: And I'm working on discrete math! Yes, "sometimes" means "at least once" and the negation would be "never". Thanks for reminding me.

Comment: It means that in mathematics. Not elsewhere. And if you mean mathematics, then you better replace "sometimes" with "at least once".